# Moving rows up and down in a datagridview and updating the database

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, row

I have a datagridview and I am getting all the data from a sql database I want to be able to move rows from one position to the other either up or down and it should also reflect the same in the database.

Currently this is what I have done and it does move the items as desired ( am adding 100 to the value of the column that am using to move up and subtracting 100 when moving down) but the problem with this is that if it find that the value of the next item in the row is lower, it doesnt move or if you add 100 then its value suddenly becomes more that 3 items above it, it doesnt move to the next position instead it moves 3 positions up, how can I simplify it to make it move just 1 row above or below respectively.

Private Sub BntMoveUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BntMoveUp.Click
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count() - 1

```
        Dim c As Boolean
        c = DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
        ' if the checkbox cell is checked
        If c = True Then
            ' MessageBox.Show("Checked")

            Dim cid As Integer = DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
            Dim cid2 As Integer = DataGridView2.Rows(i - 1).Cells(1).Value

            Str = "update Production..CMBGSeat_Staging set [Priority] =[Priority] > 1 where cid=" & cid
            updaterecords(Str)

           
            Dim cmd As Odbc.OdbcCommand
            Dim LDataadapter As Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter
            Dim MyDataset As DataSet
            Dim insert As String
            con()

            insert = "select * from Production..CMBGSeat_Staging where DateCompleted is null order by Priority desc"
            cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(insert, sqlcon)
            LDataadapter = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter
            LDataadapter.SelectCommand = cmd
            MyDataset = New DataSet

            ' MyDataset = New DataSet
            LDataadapter.Fill(MyDataset)
            DataGridView2.DataSource = MyDataset.Tables(0)


            ' if not
        Else
            '  MessageBox.Show("Not Checked")
        End If
    Next

End Sub
Private Sub BtnMoveDown_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnMoveDown.Click

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count() - 1


        Dim c As Boolean
        c = DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
        'If the Then checkbox cell Is checked
        If c = True Then
            ' MessageBox.Show("Checked")

            Dim cid As Integer = DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
            Dim cid2 As Integer = DataGridView2.Rows(i + 1).Cells(1).Value
            Str = "update Production..CMBGSeat_Staging set [Priority] =[Priority] < 1 where cid=" & cid
            updaterecords(Str)

            
            Dim cmd As Odbc.OdbcCommand
            Dim LDataadapter As Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter
            Dim MyDataset As DataSet
            Dim insert As String
            con()

            insert = "select * from Production..CMBGSeat_Staging where DateCompleted is null order by Priority desc"
            cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(insert, sqlcon)
            LDataadapter = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter
            LDataadapter.SelectCommand = cmd
            MyDataset = New DataSet

            MyDataset = New DataSet
            LDataadapter.Fill(MyDataset)
            DataGridView2.DataSource = MyDataset.Tables(0)


            ' if not
        Else
            'MessageBox.Show("Not Checked")
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: All seems a little complicated to me, why not just set a display order on the data table that the DataGridView is bound to.  Would also suggest saving and reloading the data as you're doing on every button click is horribly in-efficient.  Thought about, maybe having say a save button that saves the entire data once?  How live does the DB actually need to be.  Also consider using parameters for your sql commands rather than string concatenations

Comment: Instead of moving the cell contents around, change the row numbers of the GridViewItem and then resort the datagridview